# Unable to open my exe file once i converted

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

i converted my gui into .exe and i try to open the .exe file, it automatically close once i open it. what am i missing out to create a complete software, am i missing out os or sys or something that i need to include in. i check my codes and it work fine. this is my first time learning how to create a simple software.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import math as mt


class truepositioncal(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        super().__init__(master=master)

        # Create Frame
        self.maxtrueposition_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.nom_x_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.nom_y_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.act_x_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.act_y_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.nom_dia_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.tol_pos_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.tol_neg_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.act_dia_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.result_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.calculate_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.mmc_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.lmc_frame = tk.Frame(self)

        # prompt label Max True position
        self.promptlabelmaxpos = tk.Label(self.maxtrueposition_frame, text='Max Position Deviation:')
        # Input Max True Position
        self.maxposdev = tk.Entry(self.maxtrueposition_frame, width=10)
        self.promptlabelmaxpos.pack(side='left')
        self.maxposdev.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label nominal X
        self.labeldrawingpara_x = tk.Label(self.nom_x_frame, text='Nominal X Value:')
        self.nominal_x = tk.Entry(self.nom_x_frame, width=10)

        # pack to left (nominal X)
        self.labeldrawingpara_x.pack(side='left')
        self.nominal_x.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label nominal y
        self.labeldrawingpara_y = tk.Label(self.nom_y_frame, text='Nominal Y Value:')
        self.nominal_y = tk.Entry(self.nom_y_frame, width=10)
        self.labeldrawingpara_y.pack(side='left')
        self.nominal_y.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label actual X
        self.labelact_x = tk.Label(self.act_x_frame, text='Actual X Value:')
        self.act_x = tk.Entry(self.act_x_frame, width=10)
        self.labelact_x.pack(side='left')
        self.act_x.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label Actual Y
        self.labelact_y = tk.Label(self.act_y_frame, text='Actual Y Value:')
        self.act_y = tk.Entry(self.act_y_frame, width=10)
        self.labelact_y.pack(side='left')
        self.act_y.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label Nominal Diameter
        self.labelnomdia = tk.Label(self.nom_dia_frame, text='Nominal Diameter Value:')
        self.nom_dia = tk.Entry(self.nom_dia_frame, width=10)
        self.labelnomdia.pack(side='left')
        self.nom_dia.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label tolerance positive
        self.labeltolpos = tk.Label(self.tol_pos_frame, text='Tolerance (+) Value:')
        self.tol_pos = tk.Entry(self.tol_pos_frame, width=10)
        self.labeltolpos.pack(side='left')
        self.tol_pos.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label tolerance Negative
        self.labeltolneg = tk.Label(self.tol_neg_frame, text='Tolerance (-) Value:')
        self.tol_neg = tk.Entry(self.tol_neg_frame, width=10)
        self.labeltolneg.pack(side='left')
        self.tol_neg.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt Label for Actual Diameter
        self.labelactdia = tk.Label(self.act_dia_frame, text='Actual Diameter:')
        self.act_dia = tk.Entry(self.act_dia_frame, width=10)
        self.labelactdia.pack(side='left')
        self.act_dia.pack(side='left')

        # Create and pack the widgets for the true position results
        self.result_label = tk.Label(self.result_frame, text='Actual Position Result:')

        self.rs = tk.StringVar()
        self.rs_label = tk.Label(self.result_frame,
                                 textvariable=self.rs)

        self.result_label.pack(side='left')
        self.rs_label.pack(side='left')

        self.calc_button = tk.Button(self.calculate_frame, text='Calculate',
                                     command=self.caltruepos)

        self.calc_button.pack(side='left')

        # create widgets for MMC results
        self.mmc_result_label = tk.Label(self.mmc_frame, text='Position Tolerances allowed (MMC):')

        self.mmc = tk.StringVar()
        self.mmc_label = tk.Label(self.mmc_frame, textvariable=self.mmc)

        self.mmc_result_label.pack(side='left')
        self.mmc_label.pack(side='left')

        # create widgets for lmc results
        self.lmc_result_label = tk.Label(self.lmc_frame, text='Position Tolerances allowed (LMC):')

        self.lmc = tk.StringVar()
        self.lmc_label = tk.Label(self.lmc_frame, textvariable=self.lmc)

        self.lmc_result_label.pack(side='left')
        self.lmc_label.pack(side='left')

        # Pack into one
        self.maxtrueposition_frame.pack()
        self.nom_x_frame.pack()
        self.nom_y_frame.pack()
        self.act_x_frame.pack()
        self.act_y_frame.pack()
        self.nom_dia_frame.pack()
        self.tol_pos_frame.pack()
        self.tol_neg_frame.pack()
        self.act_dia_frame.pack()
        self.result_frame.pack()
        self.mmc_frame.pack()
        self.lmc_frame.pack()
        self.calculate_frame.pack()

    def caltruepos(self):
      #Change string into float numbers
      maxtrueposition = float(self.maxposdev.get())
      nom_x_a = float(self.nominal_x.get())
      nom_y_a = float(self.nominal_y.get())
      act_x_a = float(self.act_x.get())
      act_y_a = float(self.act_y.get())
      nom_dia_a = float(self.nom_dia.get())
      tol_pos_a = float(self.tol_pos.get())
      tol_neg_a = float(self.tol_neg.get()) 
      act_dia_a = float(self.act_dia.get())
    
      #calculate true position
      x = nom_x_a - act_x_a
      y = nom_y_a - act_y_a
      square_Root = mt.sqrt((x*x) + (y*y))
      Value = 2 * square_Root
    
      #calculate true position mmc
      a_mmc = abs(act_dia_a - (nom_dia_a - tol_neg_a)) + maxtrueposition
  
      #calculate true position lmc
      a_lmc = abs((nom_dia_a + tol_pos_a) - act_dia_a) + maxtrueposition
  
      #showing pass or fail
      if Value <= maxtrueposition:
        self.rs_label["background"] = "green"
      else:
        self.rs_label["background"] = "red"
      if Value <= a_mmc:
        self.mmc_label["background"] = "green"
      else:
        self.mmc_label["background"] = "red"
      if Value <= a_lmc:
        self.lmc_label["background"] = "green"
      else:
        self.lmc_label["background"] = "red"
      
      #roundup to 3 decimal places
      true_position_result = '{:.4f}'.format(Value)
      mmc_result = '{:.4f}'.format(a_mmc)
      lmc_result = '{:.4f}'.format(a_lmc)
  
      #float to StringVar
      self.rs.set(true_position_result)
      self.mmc.set(mmc_result)
      self.lmc.set(lmc_result)
    
main_window = tk.Tk()
# Main Window Title
main_window.title('True Position Calculator')

# main window size
main_window.geometry('400x300')

# tab notebook
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(main_window)
tab_control.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# tabs widgets
trueposcal_a = truepositioncal(tab_control)
tab_control.add(trueposcal_a,text='Shaft (OD)')

class truepositioncal1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        super().__init__(master=master)

        # Create Frame
        self.maxtrueposition_b_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.nom_x_b_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.nom_y_b_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.act_x_b_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.act_y_b_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.nom_dia_b_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.tol_pos_b_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.tol_neg_b_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.act_dia_b_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.result_b_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.calculate_b_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.mmc_b_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.lmc_b_frame = tk.Frame(self)

        # prompt label Max True position
        self.promptlabelmaxpos_b = tk.Label(self.maxtrueposition_b_frame, text='Max Position Deviation:')
        # Input Max True Position
        self.maxposdev_b = tk.Entry(self.maxtrueposition_b_frame, width=10)
        self.promptlabelmaxpos_b.pack(side='left')
        self.maxposdev_b.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label nominal X
        self.labeldrawingpara_x_b = tk.Label(self.nom_x_b_frame, text='Nominal X Value:')
        self.nominal_x_b = tk.Entry(self.nom_x_b_frame, width=10)

        #pack to left (nominal X)
        self.labeldrawingpara_x_b.pack(side='left')
        self.nominal_x_b.pack(side='left')

              # Prompt label actual X
        self.labelact_x_b = tk.Label(self.act_x_b_frame, text='Actual X Value:')
        self.act_x_b = tk.Entry(self.act_x_b_frame, width=10)
        self.labelact_x_b.pack(side='left')
        self.act_x_b.pack(side='left')
      
        # Prompt label nominal y
        self.labeldrawingpara_y_b = tk.Label(self.nom_y_b_frame, text='Nominal Y Value:')
        self.nominal_y_b = tk.Entry(self.nom_y_b_frame, width=10)
        self.labeldrawingpara_y_b.pack(side='left')
        self.nominal_y_b.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label Actual Y
        self.labelact_y_b = tk.Label(self.act_y_b_frame, text='Actual Y Value:')
        self.act_y_b = tk.Entry(self.act_y_b_frame, width=10)
        self.labelact_y_b.pack(side='left')
        self.act_y_b.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label Nominal Diameter
        self.labelnomdia_b = tk.Label(self.nom_dia_b_frame, text='Nominal Diameter Value:')
        self.nom_dia_b = tk.Entry(self.nom_dia_b_frame, width=10)
        self.labelnomdia_b.pack(side='left')
        self.nom_dia_b.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label tolerance positive
        self.labeltolpos_b = tk.Label(self.tol_pos_b_frame, text='Tolerance (+) Value:')
        self.tol_pos_b = tk.Entry(self.tol_pos_b_frame, width=10)
        self.labeltolpos_b.pack(side='left')
        self.tol_pos_b.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label tolerance Negative
        self.labeltolneg_b = tk.Label(self.tol_neg_b_frame, text='Tolerance (-) Value:')
        self.tol_neg_b = tk.Entry(self.tol_neg_b_frame, width=10)
   # move entry and label to left
        self.labeltolneg_b.pack(side='left')
        self.tol_neg_b.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt Label for Actual Diameter
        self.labelactdia_b = tk.Label(self.act_dia_b_frame, text='Actual Diameter:')
        self.act_dia_b = tk.Entry(self.act_dia_b_frame, width=10)
        self.labelactdia_b.pack(side='left')
        self.act_dia_b.pack(side='left')

              # Create and pack the widgets for the true position results
        self.result_label_b = tk.Label(self.result_b_frame, text='Actual Position Result:')

      #converting float to string variable 
        self.rs_b = tk.StringVar()
        self.rs_label_b = tk.Label(self.result_b_frame,
                                 textvariable=self.rs_b)

        self.result_label_b.pack(side='left')
        self.rs_label_b.pack(side='left')

        self.calc_button_b = tk.Button(self.calculate_b_frame, text='Calculate',
                                     command=self.caltrueposb)

        self.calc_button_b.pack(side='left')

        # create widgets for MMC results
        self.mmc_result_label_b = tk.Label(self.mmc_b_frame, text='Position Tolerances allowed (MMC):')

      #converting float to str variable
        self.mmc_b = tk.StringVar()
        self.mmc_label_b = tk.Label(self.mmc_b_frame, textvariable=self.mmc_b)

        self.mmc_result_label_b.pack(side='left')
        self.mmc_label_b.pack(side='left')

        # create widgets for lmc results
        self.lmc_result_label_b = tk.Label(self.lmc_b_frame, text='Position Tolerances allowed (LMC):')

        self.lmc_b = tk.StringVar()
        self.lmc_label_b = tk.Label(self.lmc_b_frame, textvariable=self.lmc_b)

        self.lmc_result_label_b.pack(side='left')
        self.lmc_label_b.pack(side='left')

# Pack into one
        self.maxtrueposition_b_frame.pack()
        self.nom_x_b_frame.pack()
        self.nom_y_b_frame.pack()
        self.act_x_b_frame.pack()
        self.act_y_b_frame.pack()
        self.nom_dia_b_frame.pack()
        self.tol_pos_b_frame.pack()
        self.tol_neg_b_frame.pack()
        self.act_dia_b_frame.pack()
        self.result_b_frame.pack()
        self.mmc_b_frame.pack()
        self.lmc_b_frame.pack()
        self.calculate_b_frame.pack()

    def caltrueposb(self):
      #Change string into float numbers
      maxtrueposition_bb = float(self.maxposdev_b.get())
      nom_x_bb = float(self.nominal_x_b.get())
      nom_y_bb = float(self.nominal_y_b.get())
      act_x_bb = float(self.act_x_b.get())
      act_y_bb = float(self.act_y_b.get())
      nom_dia_bb = float(self.nom_dia_b.get())
      tol_pos_bb = float(self.tol_pos_b.get())
      tol_neg_bb = float(self.tol_neg_b.get()) 
      act_dia_bb = float(self.act_dia_b.get())
    
      #calculate true position
      x = nom_x_bb - act_x_bb
      y = nom_y_bb - act_y_bb
      square_Root_b = mt.sqrt((x*x) + (y*y))
      Value_b = 2 * square_Root_b
    
      #calculate true position mmc
      bb_mmc = abs(act_dia_bb - (nom_dia_bb + tol_pos_bb)) + maxtrueposition_bb
  
      #calculate true position lmc
      bb_lmc = abs((nom_dia_bb - tol_neg_bb) - act_dia_bb) + maxtrueposition_bb
  
      #showing pass or fail
      if Value_b <= maxtrueposition_bb:
        self.rs_label_b["background"] = "green"
      else:
        self.rs_label_b["background"] = "red"
      if Value_b <= bb_mmc:
        self.mmc_label_b["background"] = "green"
      else:
        self.mmc_label_b["background"] = "red"
      if Value_b <= bb_lmc:
        self.lmc_label_b["background"] = "green"
      else:
        self.lmc_label_b["background"] = "red"
      
      #roundup to 3 decimal places
      true_position_result_b = '{:.4f}'.format(Value_b)
      mmc_result_b = '{:.4f}'.format(bb_mmc)
      lmc_result_b = '{:.4f}'.format(bb_lmc)
  
      #float to StringVar
      self.rs_b.set(true_position_result_b)
      self.mmc_b.set(mmc_result_b)
      self.lmc_b.set(lmc_result_b)    


trueposcal_b = truepositioncal1(tab_control)
tab_control.add(trueposcal_b,text='Bore (ID)')

tk.mainloop()
```

shorter version of it

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import math as mt


class truepositioncal(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        super().__init__(master=master)

        # Create Frame
        self.maxtrueposition_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.nom_x_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.nom_y_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.act_x_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.act_y_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.nom_dia_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.tol_pos_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.tol_neg_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.act_dia_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.result_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.calculate_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.mmc_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.lmc_frame = tk.Frame(self)

        # prompt label Max True position
        self.promptlabelmaxpos = tk.Label(self.maxtrueposition_frame, text='Max Position Deviation:')
        # Input Max True Position
        self.maxposdev = tk.Entry(self.maxtrueposition_frame, width=10)
        self.promptlabelmaxpos.pack(side='left')
        self.maxposdev.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label nominal X
        self.labeldrawingpara_x = tk.Label(self.nom_x_frame, text='Nominal X Value:')
        self.nominal_x = tk.Entry(self.nom_x_frame, width=10)

        # pack to left (nominal X)
        self.labeldrawingpara_x.pack(side='left')
        self.nominal_x.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label nominal y
        self.labeldrawingpara_y = tk.Label(self.nom_y_frame, text='Nominal Y Value:')
        self.nominal_y = tk.Entry(self.nom_y_frame, width=10)
        self.labeldrawingpara_y.pack(side='left')
        self.nominal_y.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label actual X
        self.labelact_x = tk.Label(self.act_x_frame, text='Actual X Value:')
        self.act_x = tk.Entry(self.act_x_frame, width=10)
        self.labelact_x.pack(side='left')
        self.act_x.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label Actual Y
        self.labelact_y = tk.Label(self.act_y_frame, text='Actual Y Value:')
        self.act_y = tk.Entry(self.act_y_frame, width=10)
        self.labelact_y.pack(side='left')
        self.act_y.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label Nominal Diameter
        self.labelnomdia = tk.Label(self.nom_dia_frame, text='Nominal Diameter Value:')
        self.nom_dia = tk.Entry(self.nom_dia_frame, width=10)
        self.labelnomdia.pack(side='left')
        self.nom_dia.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label tolerance positive
        self.labeltolpos = tk.Label(self.tol_pos_frame, text='Tolerance (+) Value:')
        self.tol_pos = tk.Entry(self.tol_pos_frame, width=10)
        self.labeltolpos.pack(side='left')
        self.tol_pos.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt label tolerance Negative
        self.labeltolneg = tk.Label(self.tol_neg_frame, text='Tolerance (-) Value:')
        self.tol_neg = tk.Entry(self.tol_neg_frame, width=10)
        self.labeltolneg.pack(side='left')
        self.tol_neg.pack(side='left')

        # Prompt Label for Actual Diameter
        self.labelactdia = tk.Label(self.act_dia_frame, text='Actual Diameter:')
        self.act_dia = tk.Entry(self.act_dia_frame, width=10)
        self.labelactdia.pack(side='left')
        self.act_dia.pack(side='left')

        # Create and pack the widgets for the true position results
        self.result_label = tk.Label(self.result_frame, text='Actual Position Result:')

        self.rs = tk.StringVar()
        self.rs_label = tk.Label(self.result_frame,
                                 textvariable=self.rs)

        self.result_label.pack(side='left')
        self.rs_label.pack(side='left')

        self.calc_button = tk.Button(self.calculate_frame, text='Calculate',
                                     command=self.caltruepos)

        self.calc_button.pack(side='left')

        # create widgets for MMC results
        self.mmc_result_label = tk.Label(self.mmc_frame, text='Position Tolerances allowed (MMC):')

        self.mmc = tk.StringVar()
        self.mmc_label = tk.Label(self.mmc_frame, textvariable=self.mmc)

        self.mmc_result_label.pack(side='left')
        self.mmc_label.pack(side='left')

        # create widgets for lmc results
        self.lmc_result_label = tk.Label(self.lmc_frame, text='Position Tolerances allowed (LMC):')

        self.lmc = tk.StringVar()
        self.lmc_label = tk.Label(self.lmc_frame, textvariable=self.lmc)

        self.lmc_result_label.pack(side='left')
        self.lmc_label.pack(side='left')

        # Pack into one
        self.maxtrueposition_frame.pack()
        self.nom_x_frame.pack()
        self.nom_y_frame.pack()
        self.act_x_frame.pack()
        self.act_y_frame.pack()
        self.nom_dia_frame.pack()
        self.tol_pos_frame.pack()
        self.tol_neg_frame.pack()
        self.act_dia_frame.pack()
        self.result_frame.pack()
        self.mmc_frame.pack()
        self.lmc_frame.pack()
        self.calculate_frame.pack()

    def caltruepos(self):
      #Change string into float numbers
      maxtrueposition = float(self.maxposdev.get())
      nom_x_a = float(self.nominal_x.get())
      nom_y_a = float(self.nominal_y.get())
      act_x_a = float(self.act_x.get())
      act_y_a = float(self.act_y.get())
      nom_dia_a = float(self.nom_dia.get())
      tol_pos_a = float(self.tol_pos.get())
      tol_neg_a = float(self.tol_neg.get()) 
      act_dia_a = float(self.act_dia.get())
    
      #calculate true position
      x = nom_x_a - act_x_a
      y = nom_y_a - act_y_a
      square_Root = mt.sqrt((x*x) + (y*y))
      Value = 2 * square_Root
    
      #calculate true position mmc
      a_mmc = abs(act_dia_a - (nom_dia_a - tol_neg_a)) + maxtrueposition
  
      #calculate true position lmc
      a_lmc = abs((nom_dia_a + tol_pos_a) - act_dia_a) + maxtrueposition
  
      #showing pass or fail
      if Value <= maxtrueposition:
        self.rs_label["background"] = "green"
      else:
        self.rs_label["background"] = "red"
      if Value <= a_mmc:
        self.mmc_label["background"] = "green"
      else:
        self.mmc_label["background"] = "red"
      if Value <= a_lmc:
        self.lmc_label["background"] = "green"
      else:
        self.lmc_label["background"] = "red"
      
      #roundup to 3 decimal places
      true_position_result = '{:.4f}'.format(Value)
      mmc_result = '{:.4f}'.format(a_mmc)
      lmc_result = '{:.4f}'.format(a_lmc)
  
      #float to StringVar
      self.rs.set(true_position_result)
      self.mmc.set(mmc_result)
      self.lmc.set(lmc_result)
    
main_window = tk.Tk()
# Main Window Title
main_window.title('True Position Calculator')

# main window size
main_window.geometry('400x300')

# tab notebook
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(main_window)
tab_control.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# tabs widgets
trueposcal_a = truepositioncal(tab_control)
tab_control.add(trueposcal_a,text='Shaft (OD)')

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]. Since the problem is with just getting the app started, you can probably illustrate the problem with a much smaller program.

Comment: but so far i i tested the codes without any error, it just the .exe that is the problem. i can reduce the code by remove the tab-1 (bore (id))

Comment: The executable created by PyInstaller 5.7.0 (for both versions) works fine.

Comment: u mean u use my codes to convert into .exe and it work fine? but i tried opening my .exe but it not working fine for me, is it i need type the right command, like pyinstaller -- newfile -F main.py?

Comment: Yes.  I use `pyinstaller -F main.py` to generate the executable.

Comment: weird i tried on my home pc, it open but shut down after the console pop out, i need find the dist folder?

Comment: i tried and it still doesn't open, it just close once the console is out

Answer (score 1):

There are many options to convert a .py to .exe

**[pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html):**

pyinstaller --onefile -w .\your_file.py

**[auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/):**

- Open your terminal and type auto-py-to-exe
- After that choose your script file
- Select One File option
- Select Window based (If you don't want the console to show)
- Also you can fill additional arguments like icon, additional files etc.
- At last click on CONVERT .PY TO .EXE

You will get the exe file in the **output/** folder

Comment: OP does not ask how to convert python script to executable.  The issue is the generated executable fails to run.

Comment: the problem is when i double click the main.exe it doesn't open

Comment: But in my case it's opens properly 